# How to observe jQuery ajax fail only for current ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jquery ajax call.

```
$$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url
}).done(function (data) {
   //do something
}).fail(function () {
    docallback()
});
```

The problem is that this will trigger sometimes both .done and .fail. I don't know how is possible that it triggers both done() and fail(). My guess is that it will trigger also fail when there is another ajax call on the same page that fails.

How can I observe fail() only for current call so it won't trigger it if there is failed call from other ajax call?

Comment: `The problem is that this will trigger sometimes both .done and .fail` This is not possible from a single AJAX call. Double check that you're not making this AJAX request in an event handler which you're accidentally invoking multiple times

Comment: You are only observing the done and fail for that current call in this code unless it's in a loop or it's been called recursively

Comment: You are actually right, it was the loop that led me to wrong conclusion.